# Odoo Breadcrumb on form view

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I have a form view and the breadcrumb is reading False. i am not sure where to set this but I would like the Partners name instead of False.

[image]

Below is my form view

```
 <record id="view_ds_repair_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ds.repair.form</field>
        <field name="model">ds.repair</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Repairs">

            <sheet>

                <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="x_partner_id"  placeholder="Customer Name"/>
                        <field name="computer_make"/>
                        <field name="password" />
                        <field name="items" widget="many2many_tags"/>                               
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="create_date"/>
                        <field name="status" />
                        <field name="priority"/>
                        <field name="estimatedrepair_cost"/>
                    </group>          
                </group>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `name` field or `rec_name` field value is empty. So you have to provide value of it. Afterwards, it will display correct information.

Comment: You can also override the name_get() method or add a field named 'display_name'.